# PowerPoint VBA - how to identify think cell object?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am struggling to work on thinkcell objects in PowerPoint. I need to execute an automation  post selecting an object on active slide. Now before I can do my task through macro, I need to identify whether any object is selected or not. If selected, whether it is a PowerPoint object or thinkcell object.

I have researched and found that I can update the thinkcell chart using tcaddin.updatechart but that is not helpful as I do not know my chart name. Also I want to check the object type of selected object and do not want to scan all the objects  in the active slide

Comment: Please provide some screenshots and the steps you performed. It will help understand the issue clearly.

Comment: I just need to add a text box below thinkcell chart. If any other chart is selected, it should pop up a message for user about wrong selection. Hope that helps

Comment: This probably does not have enough information in the question itself to keep it open. Please edit it with the necessary information (ideally involving code you have tried).

Comment: If I recall correctly, ThinkCell objects have tags that identify them. Check the tags on a known ThinkCell object to learn what they look like, then write a function you can pass the selected shape (if any) to; look for the appropriate tags and if present, return True.